# apache vhost doesn't enable

Tags: apache, virtualhost

What is wrong with this? The .conf file is added via puppet in /etc/apcahe2/sites-enabled but it doesn't get enabled and i cannot open the link abc.xyz-software.com/apis/1 ....it throws 404 error.

<VirtualHost *:80>

```
ServerAdmin   webmaster@localhost
ServerName    abc.xyz-software.com

DocumentRoot  /var/www/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-access.log combined
```

<VirtualHost *:443>

```
ServerAdmin   webmaster@localhost
ServerName    abc.xyz-software.com

DocumentRoot  /var/www/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-access.log combined

# Generic API location for global configuration
<Location "/apis">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
AuthName "LDAP Auth for API"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPBindDN dc=XYZ-DOMAIN
AuthLDAPUrl ldap://ldap.xyz-software.com/dc=XYZ-DOMAIN?sAMAccountName
Require ldap-group CN=V1_DEP_ITServ AppMgmt,OU=Departments,OU=Groups,OU=Benutzer,DC=XYZ-DOMAIN 
</Location>

<Location "/apis/1/">

ProxyPass "http://localhost:8091/" 
</Location>
```

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file show when you restart it using that configuration?

Comment: And a side note: `ServerAdmin   webmaster@localhost` does not really make sense ...

Comment: And a short look to that configuration suggests that your `Location` directives are not closed anywhere ... You need a corresponding `</Location>` closing each opened `<Location ...>` section.

Comment: location directives are there but it didn't show up in this thread....i updated now

Comment: OK, great. And the log file entries?

Comment: No, i don't see anything....but now i need to stop this task ....now i need to exclude apache configuration happening from puppet to this server...Since the nodes are defined in regex form it's very complex to exclude it .....

Comment: This is impossible. If you defined a vhost and it is not enabled there definitely is an entry in the error log file pointing out the issue. Or you completely messed up your configuration.

Comment: "it throws 404 error" - So, where is it connecting to? What's generating the 404 response?